# What does Rotations per Second * 2Pi * (Wheel Radius / Gear Ratio) equate to?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, home-experiment

Given the line of code,

```
(encoder.getVelocity() / 60) * (2 * Math.PI) * (IntakeConstants.WHEEL_RADIUS / IntakeConstants.GEARING)
```

where `encoder.getVelocity` returns rotations per minute, what does this return?

Comment: This isn't a physics question. You should probably ask it on the computational science site, or the engineering site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably wheel surface speed - rotations/second*$2\pi$=radians per second, radians per second*radius=translational speed. From context, gear ratio is probably defined the right way round for this to calculate the speed of the object from the motor rpm